# Animating an emission shader (or any)

Tags: animation, node-editor, shaders, timeline, emission

This is my first time posting here, I'm still relatively new to blender. I'm having trouble animating my emission shader. I'm trying to achieve like a blinking effect or an even brighter emission (at a certain point in the shot) but I'm not sure how to go about it.

If anyone could give me any tips, that would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

While howering mouse over a *Strength* value in *Emission* node, you can press <kbd>I</kbd> key to insert a keyframe for this parameter. Move in *Timeline* to another frame. Move mouse over node strength parameter and press shortcut again.

[image]

To adjust blending between keyframes to get on /off effect switch to Graph Editor, select all keyframes and switch handle type from Bezier to Constant (T).

Comment: Ah, thank you so much!! I've been at this for a while haha.